# Trajectory file analysis using Python

Tags: python, numpy, file, analysis, frames

First of all, I am very new to python.
I have a large trajectory file with multi-time steps (50000) and what I am trying to do is write a python code which calculates the mean square displacement of water Oxygen(O) atoms.

My plan is to first select Oxygen atoms frame by frame and then carry out with the MSD code. In a single frame of my trajectory file the first 2 lines contains the total number of atoms(5058) and atom description respectively for that perticular frame, after that the next 606 lines contain the surface atoms and the remaining 4450 lines contain the water atoms in an orderly manner(O,H,H,O,H,H,O,H,H, etc) I started like this but I feel like I am going nowhere.

```py
  import numpy as np 
  import math
  
  #parameters
 
 
 m_o     = 16 #gmol-1                                                  
 m_h     = 1 #gmol-1
 leave   = 608 #including the two title lines first 606 atoms are surface atms.so they should be just read
 waters  = 4450 #after the first 606 atoms the rest are water atoms
 N       = 5060 #number of lines in a frame
 
 
 with open("traj.xyz","r") as f:
    count = len(f.readlines(  )) #counts the total number of lines
 #print(count)
 nof = count/N
 '''nof is number of frames'''
 print(int(nof))
 
 def frames():
    for i in nof:
        count = 0
        xcoord = []
        ycoord = []
        zcoord = []
        for i in range(leave):
            title = f.readline()
            for line in f:
                cnt+=1
                if (cnt % 3 == 1):
                    atmid,x,y,z = line.split()
                    xcoord.append(x)
                    ycoord.append(y)
                    zcoord.append(z)
                    print(atmid,x,y,z)

 if (cnt == waters):
    exit()                                                                
 frames()
```

Comment: Character alignment (i.e. tbas) are very important in python coding and whatever you have done with that code formatting they have all been destroyed, so your code is unreadable.  Please fix so we can help.  Also please try to keep information in the question to things relevant to programming, as most of us can't follow chemistry jargon or even tell what you want based on chemistry terms.

Comment: Please format your code correctly - select it with your mouse and click `{}` in the formatting toolbar beside **Bold** and *Italic*. Please also provide samples of the various parts of your trajectory file and also details of the calculations you wish to make. Thank you.